# Tell lessphp to compile css AND less files instead only less?

Tags: php, less

Leafos great php class 
http://leafo.net/lessphp/
helps us compile all less files in to 1 css file and call it in our web/template head.

Now this is a great tool but 1 issue I have with it is;
All my previous joomla work has used following css folder files structure

```
-css
--style.css
--post.css
--comments.css
--color.css
```

than in template head I call only style.css and within that file 
I used

```
@import url("post.css"); 
@import url("comments.css"); 
@import url("color.css");
```

Now Joomla 3.1 is including leafos class and bootsrap in core and they will have a default less folder placed in template folder where you should place all your less files to be compiled.

in order for me to convert templates to use less and bootstrap  I would have to convert all those css files extensions to less
and move them to less folder , 
what I am trying to preserve is backwards compatibility with pre joomla 3.0 templates and making double files kinda makes no sense.

isnt there any way that lessphp can compile already existing .css files from css folder instead me making double files structure?

something like

```
$less->checkedCompile("css/style.css", "css/style.css");
```

instead

```
$less->checkedCompile("less/style.less", "css/style.css");
```

I tried

placing style.less in less folder and on top do

```
@import "../../../media/jui/less/hero-unit.less";
.. all other boostrap depending less files.. 

@import url("../css/post.css");
```

but the generated file is compiling all bootstrap files and just including the post.css @import and not compiling it

Hope I did not confuse you to much.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: by commenting line 103 in lessphp  we can import and recompile css files if (substr_compare($url, '.css', -4, 4) === 0) return false; I am still testing this to make sure there are no issues but so far it works ok

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lessc version 0.4.0
try commenting the following lines that says

// don't import if it ends in css

if (substr_compare($url, '.css', -4, 4) === 0) return false;